# How to get corresponding price of the smallest date chosen in date slicer in Power BI

Tags: charts, powerbi, visualization, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am quite new to working with DAX and Power BI so please don't judge. My problem seems (and might be) simple. Anyways, here we go:

I have a dataset that contains 3 colulmns: Date (date), Price (float), Performance (%)

Attribute descriptions:
Date and Price are constants that are pulled from an external data source. Performance is a variable of the price change over time in percent. It is the percentage change of the price of the current date to the first date in the time-series selection (Selected "from date" of date slicer visual).

I want to create a dynamic line chart that shows performance over time. Difficulty here is when I change the "from date" I want the performance to be variable. Meaning, the price of the chosen "from date" is the new base price and should be calculated accordingly.

Formula:
Date = t, price at date t = pt, performance at date t = pert

Date range:
1.1.2000 to 31.12.2010

Initial situation when "date from" in the date slicer visual = 1.1.2000:

- t0 = 1.1.2000
- pt0 = 5,00
- pert0 = 0%
- t5 = 6.1.2000
- pt5 = 5,054
- pert5 = (pt5-pt0)/pt0 = 1.08%

After changing date slicer so that "from date" is now 10.10.2009:

- t0new = 10.10.2009
- pt0new = 9,938
- pert0new = 0%
- t5new = 15.10.2009
- pt5new = 9,832
- pert5new = (pt5-pt0)/pt0 = -1,05%

As described, I want whatever is selected as starting point from the date slicer as the new base value for the performance calculation and the line chart should adjust accordingly.

I know how to do the dynamic line chart but I cannot figure out the measures and calculated columns I need to do so.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Cheers, 
MLU

Answer (score 1):

1. Calculate the benchmark as the price associated to the first date in
   the period. `SELECTEDVALUE` **assumes you have one price per Date**,
   otherwise use an aggregator (e.g. `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVERAGE`). I use ALLSELECTED so the Benchmark is affected only by Filter Context (slicers) and you can easily use it in visualizations that change the context.
2. Save our benchmark in a variable for later use
3. Divide each price by the benchmark. Here we need to apply an aggregator to the Price, 
   I used AVERAGE assuming you have only one Price per day, therefore, the result is the 
   price itself.

Here is the measure:

```
Price vs Dynamic Benchmark :=
VAR vbenchmark = CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE(Dataset[Price]),FILTER(ALL( Dataset[Date]), Dataset[Date] = CALCULATE(min(Dataset[Date])), ALLSELECTED(Dataset))
return
AVERAGE(Price) / vbenchmark
```

Comment: Hi Seymour, Thanks for your input, it does seem to make a lot of sense. However, I do have difficulties applying your code to the measure. After editing it accordingly to my data set I am still left with an error: Failed to resolve name 'Date'. It is not a valid table, variable, or function name.

Apologies in advance if that is a trivial question, but is Date another variable that needs to be defined or is there something else wrong? 

Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Date should be Dataset[Date]. Fixed.

Comment: Hi Seymour! 

Again, thanks for your time and effort. This did not solve it either. 

Here is the adjusted query but now I get a different error, but this time in correlation with the CALCULATE function. (A function 'CALCULATE' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.)
`Price vs Dynamic Benchmark = 
VAR vbenchmark = CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE('Input Data'[Price]), 'Input Data'[NAV_Date] = CALCULATE(MIN('Input Data'[NAV_Date]), ALLSELECTED('Input Data')))
RETURN
AVERAGE('Input Data'[Price]) / vbenchmark`

Comment: Correct, we had to use filter in order to apply a filter in the row context.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @Seymour! 

Please see the final code that solved my problem: 

```
DynamicPerformance =   
VAR vdate =  
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Input Data'[NAV_Date] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'Input Data' ) )  
VAR vbenchmark =  
    CALCULATE (  
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Input Data'[Price] ),  
        'Input Data'[NAV_Date] = vdate  
    )  
RETURN  
      (AVERAGE ( 'Input Data'[Price] ) - vbenchmark)/vbenchmark